# Width of component incorrect after resize across @media tag in CSS

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm new to web development, thrown into a group from an embedded team.

The problem goes like this. we've got an array of cards we display a horizontal timeline each. basically

[label, timeline]

[label, timeline]

[label, timeline]

on the window resize. sometimes, the timeline will jump to a newline below the label.

in the CSS we have a couple @media tags that set the width of each card

```css
@media (min-width:1269px) and (max-width: 1365px) {

.cardContainer { width: calc((610px * 2) + 48px);

}

.cardContainerInner {
  display: block;
  /*transition: all 1s !important;*/
```

I commented out the transition tag to test my theory that it was causing the problem and it looks like it is.

it made the cards readjust themselves nice and pretty so I'd like to keep it:

got some divs and my bar graph line inside:

```
<div class="cardContainer">
  <div class="somecard cardContainer cardContainerInner " #innerCard
  <bar-graph-app             style="display:block"
                             [width]="width"
                             [height]="height"
      ></bar-graph-app>
```

That Bar graph app, I override ngOnChanges to take the width and calculate the number of pixels each section of the timeline

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

if(changes.hasOwnProperty('width')) { //calculate width of each timeline section } }
```

generally speaking it does the calculation correctly, Until you resize your browser just across that @media boundary

when that happens

it catches the ngonchanges, but the width value is the value before the transition starts, so the old value gets used and my overall timeline width is too big.

resizing it again within that boundary gets the correct width and fixes the display. getting rid of the transition parameter also fixes the problem.

How can I get that width to update correctly, after the transition is complete?

Answer (score 1):

you have to listen for the transitionend event, which is fired when a CSS transition completes.

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

// ...

@HostListener('transitionend', ['$event'])
handleTransitionEnd(event: TransitionEvent) {
    if (event.propertyName === 'width') { // Check if the transitioned property is 'width'
        this.recalculateWidth();
    }
}
```

Move the width calculation logic to a separate method, so you can call it both from ngOnChanges and the handleTransitionEnd method.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.hasOwnProperty('width')) {
        this.recalculateWidth();
    }
}

recalculateWidth() {
    // Calculate width of each timeline section
}
```